# Handle project reload event in Visual Studio SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I'd like to check and update csproj file if a specified item in csproj is updated.

[DocumentSaved event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dispdocumentevents_event.documentsaved.aspx) is not fired when csproj file is saved.
So I want to handle project reload event or csproj file save event.

Does anyone has in idea for it?

postscript:

To be specific, I'd like to rewrite HintPath with SolutionDir property ($(SolutionDir)\packages\.. ) instead of relative path(..\packages\.. ) after HintPath is added or updated via Nuget.

The answer by Matze works fine!

Comment: On save of the file? Or on build of the csproj? You could use build events https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the `_dispDocumentEvents_Event` interface says...

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.
>
> Microsoft Internal Use Only.

Of course, the interface is public, but the usage is rarely documented and it´s availability and function might change or could be removed in a future version of the IDE. I would not recommend to use it as a foundation for custom extension functionality.

Instead you could use the `IVsRunningDocumentTable` service and a custom implementation of the `IVsRunningDocTableEvents` interface, which provides similiar functionality by the `AfterSave` event. I would suggest an implementation of a class that handles subscription to events and hides unnecessary details. For instance...

```
internal abstract class RunningDocumentTableEvents : 
    IDisposable,
    IVsRunningDocTableEvents
{
    private readonly IVsRunningDocumentTable rdt;

    private readonly uint sinkCookie;

    public RunningDocumentTableEvents(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.rdt = serviceProvider.GetSerice(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable)) 
            as IVsRunningDocumentTable;

        uint cookie;
        this.rdt.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(this, out cookie);
        this.sinkCookie = cookie;
    }

    protected abstract void OnAfterSave(AfterSaveEventArgs e);

    int IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnAfterSave(uint docCookie)
    {
        uint flags, readLocks, editLocks, itemId;
        string moniker;
        IVsHierarchy hierarchy;
        IntPtr docData;

        int hr = this.rdt.GetDocumentInfo(
            docCookie, out flags, out readLocks, out editLocks, out moniker,
            out hierarchy, out itemId, out docData);

        if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
        {
            var e = new AfterSaveEventArgs { FileName = moniker, ... };
            this.OnAfterSave(e);
        }

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.rdt.UnadviseRunningDocTableEvents(this.sinkCookie);
    }
}
```

The `OnAfterSave` callback receives a cookie which can be passed to the `GetDocumentInfo` method of an `IVsRunningDocumentTable` object in order to obtain the document´s filename, locks, the related hierarchy item as well as a pointer to an `IVsTextBuffer` that holds the documents data.